# CakePHP limit association

Tags: php, cakephp, associations

I try to write a message system like on facebook.
I got Tables;

```
USERS
id, name

MESSAGES
user_from, user_to, message
```

And i got models:

```
USER

public $hasMany = array(
      'MessageFrom' => array(
          'className' => 'Message',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_from'
      ),
      'MessageTo' => array(
          'className' => 'Message',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_to'
      )
  );
  var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'UserMessages' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'joinTable' => 'messages',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_from',
          'associationForeignKey' => 'user_to'
      )
  );

MESSAGE

public $belongsTo = array(
      'UserFrom' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_from'
      ),
      'UserTo' => array(
          'className' => 'User',
          'foreignKey' => 'user_to'
      )
  );
```

Everything is working good, i mean send and recive mesages from users, and reading it.
But i want to do chats list in user panel.

I must select all users with only last message to create list of chats with users.

My array looks like:

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'Message' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'user_from' => '2',
            'user_to' => '1',
            'message' => 'Hello user 1!',
        ),
        'UserFrom' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'username' => 'user2',
        ),
        'UserTo' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'username' => 'user1',
        )
),
(int) 1 => array(
        'Message' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'user_from' => '1',
            'user_to' => '2',
            'message' => 'Oh Hello user 2!',
        ),
        'UserFrom' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'username' => 'user1',
        ),
        'UserTo' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'username' => 'user2',
        )
),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'Message' => array(
            'id' => '12',
            'user_from' => '1',
            'user_to' => '5',
            'message' => 'Message to user 5 from user 1',
        ),
        'UserFrom' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'username' => 'user1',
        ),
        'UserTo' => array(
            'id' => '5',
            'username' => 'user5',
        )
),
```

And now for ex im logged as user id = 1 i want to see in my chat lists

USER 5 (last message: Message to user 5 from user 1)
USER 2 (last message: Oh hello user 1)

Simpy: i want to have only one last message to or from users in this array... 
I dont need list of all messages... Only one last mesage from or to user, like in GMAIL box.
Now in array i have all user and messages associations...

I create a function... It gets all mesages with users...
How to get only one mesage with greatest id ?

```
public function getChats($user_id) {
    $this->order = 'Message.date DESC, Message.id DESC';
    $data = $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('user_to' => $user_id),
                array('user_from' => $user_id)
            )
        )
    ));
    return $data;
  }
```

-

```
SELECT `Message`.`id`, `Message`.`user_from`, `Message`.`user_to`, `Message`.`message`, `Message`.`date`, `UserFrom`.`id`, `UserFrom`.`username`, `UserFrom`.`email`, `UserFrom`.`password`, `UserFrom`.`name`, `UserFrom`.`surname`, `UserFrom`.`city`, `UserFrom`.`street`, `UserFrom`.`born_date`, `UserFrom`.`role`, `UserTo`.`id`, `UserTo`.`username`, `UserTo`.`email`, `UserTo`.`password`, `UserTo`.`name`, `UserTo`.`surname`, `UserTo`.`city`, `UserTo`.`street`, `UserTo`.`born_date`, `UserTo`.`role` FROM `gametrade_cake`.`messages` AS `Message` LEFT JOIN `gametrade_cake`.`users` AS `UserFrom` ON (`Message`.`user_from` = `UserFrom`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `gametrade_cake`.`users` AS `UserTo` ON (`Message`.`user_to` = `UserTo`.`id`) WHERE ((`user_to` = 1) OR (`user_from` = 1)) 
GROUP BY UserFrom.id,UserTo.id
ORDER BY `Message`.`id` DESC
```

This query select my messages, but i dont know why dont order it by message.id DESC...
This order by mesage.id ASC...

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Kindly write a query by which you are getting the above result. So that I can help a bit fast.

Comment: You can't limit the results from associated models running only one query. You have to run a second query or run a complex/raw SQL query to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass one timestamp while querying the messages, you must be saving timestamp while saving the message

```
public function getChats($user_id,$timestamp) {
    $this->order = 'Message.date DESC, Message.id DESC';
    $data = $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('user_to' => $user_id),
                array('user_from' => $user_id)
            ),
            'created >' => $timestamp 
        )
    ));
    return $data;
  }
```